# Generic Repository. FindByID

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository, repository-pattern

I am playing around with making a nhibernate generic repo but I am unsure how to make a method to return an entity back by ID

```
 public class NhibernateRepo : INhibernateRepo
    {
        private readonly ISession session;

        public NhibernateRepo(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
        }

        public void Create<T>(T entity)
        {
            session.Save(entity);
        }

        public void CreateOrUpdate<T>(T entity)
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
        }

        public void Delete<T>(T entity)
        {
            session.Delete(entity);
        }

        public void Update<T>(T entity)
        {
            session.Update(entity);
        }

        public T Get<T>(object id)
        {
            return session.Get<T>(id);
        }

        public T Load<T>(object id)
        {
            return session.Load<T>(id);
        }

        public void ReadOnly(object entity, bool readOnly = true)
        {
            session.SetReadOnly(entity, readOnly);
        }

        public void Evict(object entity)
        {
            session.Evict(entity);
        }

        public object Merge(object entity)
        {
            return session.Merge(entity);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>()
        {
            return session.Query<T>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't your Get method do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define this method in the repository interface:

```
interface IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class {

    TEntity FindById(TId id); 
    ...
}
```

And following in repository implementation:

```
class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class{
    public TEntity FindById(TId id) {
        return _session.Get<TEntity>(id);
    }
}
```

As a side note, generic repository **interface** is sometimes considered to be a [bad practice](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/) from Domain Driven Design perspective.